# What triggers the trim horn and the "stabilizer motion" aural callout on the MD80?

Tags: avionics, md-80

I got conflicting or incomplete responses from various sources:

> There is an internal rate monitor looking to see the stabilizer is
>   actually moving .08°/sec or -08°/sec.

https://forums.tfdidesign.com/index.php?/topic/2509-bbetty-stabilizer-motion-warning/

> The trim horn will sound each 1/2 degree of constant pilot use, but
>   the stabilizer motion call will sound when the auto pilot moves the
>   trim 2 degrees within 30 seconds.

https://forums.x-plane.org/index.php?/forums/topic/123539-cockpit-sounds/

> The CAWS will provide an aural warning (tone and voice) when the
>   horizontal stabilizer deviates one degree or more for a given length
>   of time. The warning will be on until the horizontal stabilizer sensor
>   goes off.

https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=751253

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aural sounds, the horn, and the voice callout "stabilizer motion".

- The horn sounds every 0.5° of trim change after the initial 0.5–1°.
- "Stabilizer motion" sounds when the autopilot or runaway trim motor make a >2° in 30 seconds.

So your second source is the correct one. See text below from an MD-80 flight manual:

> Momentary horn sound starts after 0.5º to 1.0º of stabilizer movement and repeats every 0.5º of stabilizer movement . "STABILIZER MOTION" voice warnings will sound when either the autopilot or a runaway trim motor moves the stabilizer more than 2º in 30 seconds and will continue to sound as long as stabilizer moves. Cycle continues until stabilizer movement ceases. ([Manual page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlu4e.png))

Note that it also says:

> Vocal warning on some aircraft, other aircraft no vocal warning.

So not all MD-80s have the voice saying "stabilizer motion".

Comment: Thanks a lot, that clears it up!